# Is it possible to use Google Apps Script to send a text message when a missed call is received?

Tags: google-apps-script, voice

Just posted this in the [Google Voice forums](http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/voice/OfN1_DN1l0o/discussion), but I was wondering if it was possible to use Google Apps Scripts to go out and check my Google Voice Inbox for any unread missed calls and send myself a text when a new one arrives.

Answer (score 5):

You CAN send sms/mms using Google Apps Script.

- Let's say your google voice number is 1(555)999-1111 and your cell number is 1(555)111-2222. From your cell phone, send a sms to your GV number.
- Opening your gmail, you will find the text message. Notice the from address will be `15559991111.15551112222.rAndomChars@txt.voice.google.com` where the first number is your GV number, the number after the first dot is your cell number And there are 10 random numbers/letters after the second dot.
- Copy this email address and use it as the to address in your google Apps Script.
- If you want to send a text message to another cell number, have them SMS your GV number and save that email address.
- If you run your script from another account, you will need to repeat the process of getting the proper email address because the random characters will change.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script doesn't provide native support for sending text messages or checking Google Voice.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can send and SMS, but only if the recipient first "enable SMS notifications on invites in their own Google Calendar" https://gist.github.com/1658408

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this would work exactly, since I'm very new to scripting, but have you tried using Gmail?  Your Google Voice settings allow you to receive an email any time you miss a call or get a text message.

Theoretically, you could bypass Google Apps Script entirely by setting up text message alerts for Gmail and create a filter that sends them whenever you get an email from Google Voice about a missed call.

But if you still wanted to go through Google Apps script, you may be able to modify the [Inbox Statistics Report script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/gmail-stats).

First, you would have to enable emails for text messages and then send a text message to your Google Voice number, that will give you an email address you use to send texts from GV to your cell phone.  Then you might be able to modify that script to scan your inbox at a certain interval for an email about a missed call, and if it picks one up, it could send a message to the email address that sends from GV to your cell phone.

That seems like a lot of work, though, so like I said it may just be easier to use Gmail's texting alerts.